# google cloud datastore | getting uncertain record

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, memcached, cluster-computing, multiple-instances

In my application I am using `google cloud datastore`,whenever I am fetching record from db getting uncertain results.I am explaining my scenarios in detail-

**Step1**-Persist Entity.

```
{
organisationId": null,
"providerId": 5086313359343616,
"jonelId",755668
}
```

**Step2**-Fetched the same record,and get below result as expected.

```
{
organisationId": null,
"providerId": 5086313359343616,
"jonelId",755668
}
```

**Step3**-Update Entity.Changed organisationId `null` to `8965313359343729`.

**Step4**-fetched Entity again.

Now I am getting uncertain result,both of the below results I am getting I sub sequences hit,until next deployment.

```
{
    organisationId": 8965313359343729,
    "providerId": 5086313359343616,
    "jonelId",755668
    }
```

or

```
{
    organisationId": null,
    "providerId": 5086313359343616,
    "jonelId",755668
    }
```

**Step4**-Deployment,and fetch Entity.

Now I am getting updated Entity Every time.

```
{
    organisationId": 8965313359343729,
    "providerId": 5086313359343616,
    "jonelId",755668
    }
```

What could be reason of this uncertainty,I have not enabled caching manually,Is google cloud datastore by default did it for us,or there is some other issue behind this.

Comment: How do you fetch?

Comment: `entityManager.find(EntityName.class, id);` entityManager is of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Comment: how do you update your Entity? can you please post the Code?

Comment: This relates to eventual consistency with the datastore: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/data-consistency

Comment: System is Auto scaled but both instance is not sharing datastore/cache/else.how to get rid from this.